# eyes rigging with metarig

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I just made a pair of eyes to rig in a character. They are made of 3 parts: the iris, the eyeball and the transparent cornea in front of the iris. the problem here is when these items are rotated, the eyes become deformed and lose their original form. What should I do?

Comment: Usually you create a base element for the rotation (eg: eyeball) and rotate it. Other side-elements (eg: iris, glass) are parented to the eyeball (if they have their object origin in the same place as the ejeball, they will rotate in the same way).

Comment: Parent everything to the eyeball and use a track to constraint to a pair of empties